# background image slider for body tag

Tags: jquery, wordpress, background-image, slide

I am looking for a way to have multiple background images slide or toggle for my `<body>` tag. The problem I have encountered the past 3 hours is that every script wants a fixed width and height for the element. 
Can anyone help ?

Comment: It is unclear what you want here. Do you want to replace the whole body?

Comment: i just want to find a script to slide multiple background images, sadly so far everything i found needs a fiex height and width of the body element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the details you've provided, it sounds like you are just looking for a basic slide show on your `<body>`'s background-image. This is basic, but something like this should do it for you.

```
(function($, interval, slides) {

    var i = 0;
    var handle = setInterval(function () {


        $('body').css("background-image", "url('" + slides[i] + "')");

        i++;

        if (i >= slides.length) {
            i = 0;
        }
    }, interval);

})(jQuery, 1000, [
    "/slide1.jpg",
    "/slide2.jpg",
    "/slide3.jpg"
]);
```

Interval is the time between images in milliseconds (so, 1000 = 1 second), and then paste in the paths to your slides for slide1.jpg, slide2.jpg, etc...

Bear in mind, you'll want appropriately sized images and your CSS will need to handle sizing and positioning.

Comment: yea i know at least that much :)
thank you ill try it out :)
btw the tags are <script type="text/javascript"> your code </script> ?
didnt do js for some time , forgot

Comment: Yep, you got it right @NecrosAeturnus. :) You could also paste it into a separate JS file and include it on your page with <script type="text/javascript" src="path_to_my_js_file.js" ></script>. It's fine to place in the <head> or <body> tag.

Comment: i placed it at the end of the head tag, sorry for being so noob , i really didnt do this for some time, btw setInterval(function () , is there another closing bracket missing ? something like setInterval(function (), 1000) ?

Comment: "}, interval);" is now "}, 1000);" still not working :/

Comment: @NecrosAeturnus, you were right, I should have specified 1000 as the parameter. I've updated the code to be correct. Sorry for the confusion!

Comment: It works, just had to add a library :D 
got anything do add a fade,slide ... animation speed ? xD

Comment: @NecrosAeturnus, you probably want to look into the CSS transitions (https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/t/transition/) and CSS animations (https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/a/animation/) properties. Bear in mind, background-image is not transitionable, but you could probably get clever with background-position and background-size properties. Also, there's this: https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/

Comment: wait so instead of adding something like sliding speed i can just add a transition: 1s ease all ?

Comment: ok seriously you just blew my mind, i wasnt aware that a simple transition works that well on js, if you ever end up in Croatia, even for vacation you got at least a drink on me :D